# How to get app's statistics of the Developer-console via Android itself?

Tags: android, gsutil

### Background

I wish to get app's statistics that are available on the [**Developer-console website**](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/), but via Android itself, as an app.

### What I've found

Google has a tool to get your app's reports (statistics, reviews, etc...) , called "[**gsutil**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil)" (more info [**here**](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#export)). I think it can do more, but that's what I wish to try out.

### The problem

This tool is written in Python, and therefore it cannot be launched so easily on Android (and a bit on other Os's too, as you have to install Python runtime for this).

### The question

Is there any way to use it on Android? Or maybe an alternative?

How about a library that does the same?

Comment: Rather than asking about using a particular tool, I suggest you describe what you actually want to achieve.  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?  It's extremely unclear from your question.

Comment: I want to get statistics about apps (via Android), using whatever is available by Google. I've found "gsutil" and I think this is the official way to do it, but I can't find out how to do it on Android. I've updated the question to be more general. Hope now you understand.

Comment: I think you should look at the source of that gsutil tool - I'm pretty sure it just calls some API over the network - and translate it to java to be done inside your app.

Comment: @AleksG Quite a large project for me to convert. I've written now a request there: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/257

Comment: So, gsutil is the command-line tool interface to Google Cloud Storage, and is very likely not the application you want. What dashboard and/or statistics are you talking about? https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html? Some other site?

Comment: No, this one: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/ . I'd like to get as many information from there as possible. I like the graphs more, but the reviews information can also be nice, especially if it includes all of them and not just those that have text in them.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Andlytics app. They were able to accomplish this.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.andlyticsproject

Comment: That's an app, not something I can develop with. Not API, not SDK, and you are not showing how to do it . Great app though.

Comment: I was looking for an API but didn't exactly find one. I came across appfigures.com which has pulls data from Google Play Developer Console. They have an API which you can interface with.